# Swift: Triggering TableViewCell to lead to a link in a UIWebView in another ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, ios9, didselectrowatindexpath

When i tap a `tableViewCell` I want a link (that is specific to that cell's `indexPath.row`) to open up in a new viewController with a webView.

Example: I tap the 3rd cell in the `tableView` and www.apple.com opens up on a new viewController.

I'm trying to do that with `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` but I can't figure out how to put the code together so that the code from the `linksArray` (where i have all the links stored) works together when I tap the `tableViewCell`

I'm querying these links from Parse.com. This is my array:

`var linksArray = [NSURL](`)

I created a new Class called `LinkViewViewController` where I have just the webView connected as a `@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!` and nothing else. I took out the `viewDidLoad` method so that I can control the `LinkViewViewController` from the `FeedTableViewController` class that has the cells.

Here's my code below

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,  didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let myWebView = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell",    forIndexPath: indexPath) as! LinkViewViewController

    var url = NSURL(string:"\(links[indexPath.row])")

    var request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)

    myWebView.webView.loadRequest(links[indexPath.row] as! NSURLRequest)

}
```

**UPDATE**

I am also trying to do it this way, which maybe more logical. I am accessing the links that are stored in Parse in the ProductInfo class. The `productName` array represents in what order the cells are organized in so that the the links can be accessed when tapping on the product name.

```
   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,  didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let myWebView = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell",    forIndexPath: indexPath) as! LinkViewViewController
  //Assuming that myWebView is the right method/way to go about it. 

    var link = PFObject(className: "ProductInfo")

    link["pLink"] = productName[indexPath.row]


       /* Code missing: I'm accessing where the link is (the
        indexPath.row) associated with the productName. 
        I don't know how to go about this now... How do i access the 
        webView in the other viewController where the corresponding 
        link appears?

        */
}
```

I've also tried creating a segue from the cell to the webView but that didn't work either...

How can I set up the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` so that a link is triggered to appear in a new view?

Thought: `NSTransportSecurity` in the `info.plist` also an issue?

Any helps means a lot.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm unclear - is the webView embedded in the tableViewCell, or is it displayed modally/pushed over the full tableViewController?

Comment: @pbasdf sorry, I don't understand the question... The webView is in it's own separate UIViewController in the MainStoryBoard and has its own class. I'm assuming that I should access it from the TableViewController class because that's where I'm tapping the cell which ultimately leads to the link associated with that cell. Hope that answered your question...

Comment: Thanks, that helps...

Comment: Thank you. Just to know, I added some more code of another way I'm going about it... Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` to create your next view controller.  You should use the storyboard's `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` to create the instance:  Set the "Storyboard ID" for the viewController in your storyboard

[image: Storyboard image]

If you set it to, for example, "WebViewController" you can then create the instance with:

```
let myWebView = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("WebViewController") as! LinkViewViewController
```

My recommendation would be to give the `LinkViewViewController` its own URL property,

```
var url : NSURL?
```

and to pass the URL after creating the instance:

```
myWebView.url = url
```

and then present the new VC:

```
self.presentViewController(myWebView, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

In the `viewDidLoad` of LinkViewViewController, load the URL into the webView:

```
let URLRequest = NSURLRequest(self.url)
self.webView.loadRequest(URLRequest)
```

(Typed without testing; please forgive any typos/errors with optionals etc).

As a final note, this method uses the `didSelectRow` method to create the view controller instance and pass the URL.  Another option would be to use a segue by ctrl-dragging from the prototype cell to the view controller.  You then need to implement similar code in `prepareForSegue` method to set the url.

Comment: Thank you. I'm getting a crash at ` let URLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: (self.url)!)' in the LinkViewViewController. Just a few questions: 1) i did this:  'myWebView.url = NSURL(string: linksArray[indexPath.row])' is that what you meant by `url`? 2. in the ViewDidLoad of the LinKViewController, should i just leave it as it? `let URLRequest = NSURLRequest(self.url)` ? Otherwise, as mentioned i get a `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Comment: Both look good to me.  Can you step through, or use print() to check which value is nil?

Comment: I'm unable to print the `URLRequest` nor the `url` variable. Stepping through isn't doing me any good either but it point me to `LinkViewViewController `.  I'm assuming the issue is with var url: NSURL? because its the only optional, and it's also called in the URLRequest. Not sure what to do about that... I am already printing to the logs the links that I'm loading. So I do see them. Maybe I'm not converting them correctly from a String in Parse to a NSURL in Swift?

Comment: Try using a test URL: `myWebView.url = NSURL(string:"http:...whatever...")`

Comment: Great idea... It didn't work. It had the same crash.

Comment: Is the tableViewCell linked to the LinkViewViewController by a segue?

Comment: Yes. I also tried linking the viewController itself. I get a libstdc++ error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92666/discussion-between-rinyfo4-and-pbasdf).