# Handle selection of custom CallOutView swift

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview

I've created a custom callOutView, which seem to work fine. However i have problem with handling tap on the custom callOut view. I would like push to a specific viewController when it is selected. How can i achieve this?

below i've added my `FBSingleClusterView`, which is the custom MKAnnotationView and the `bubbleView` which is the custom callOutView. beside this i ofcourse have an viewController with a mapView.

**FBSingleClusterView Variables**

```
private var hitOutside:Bool = true


var preventDeselection:Bool {
    return !hitOutside
}
```

**FBSingleClusterView methods**

```
override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {

    let calloutViewAdded = bubbleView?.superview != nil

    if (selected || !selected && hitOutside) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }

    self.superview?.bringSubviewToFront(self)

    if (bubbleView == nil) {
        bubbleView = BubbleView()
    }

    if (self.selected && !calloutViewAdded) {
        bubbleView?.clipsToBounds = true
        bubbleView?.layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.addSubview(bubbleView!)

        let discView = UIImageView()
        discView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.Center
        discView.image = UIImage()
        discView.image = UIImage(named: "Disclosure")

        bubbleView?.contentView.addSubview(discView)


        let nameLabel = UILabel()
        nameLabel.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]
        nameLabel.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(10)
        nameLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        nameLabel.text = companyString?.uppercaseString


        bubbleView?.addSubview(nameLabel)

        discView.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
            make.top.equalTo(bubbleView!).offset(0)
            make.height.equalTo(30)
            make.width.equalTo(20)
            make.right.equalTo(bubbleView!).offset(0)

        }

        nameLabel.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
            make.top.equalTo(bubbleView!).offset(0)
            make.left.equalTo(bubbleView!).offset(10)
            make.height.equalTo(30)
            make.right.equalTo(bubbleView!).offset(-20)
        }

        let nameLabelWidth = nameLabel.requiredWidth(companyString!.uppercaseString, font: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(10)) + 35

        let bubbleHeight = 35 as CGFloat

        bubbleView?.frame = CGRectMake((self.frame.width/2)-(nameLabelWidth/2), -bubbleHeight-2, nameLabelWidth, bubbleHeight)

    }

    if (!self.selected) {
        bubbleView?.removeFromSuperview()
    }



}

override func hitTest(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
    var hitView = super.hitTest(point, withEvent: event)

    if let callout = bubbleView {
        if (hitView == nil && self.selected) {
            hitView = callout.hitTest(point, withEvent: event)
        }
    }

    hitOutside = hitView == nil

    return hitView;
}
```

**bubbleView methods**

```
    override public func hitTest(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        let viewPoint = superview?.convertPoint(point, toView: self) ?? point

        //      let isInsideView = pointInside(viewPoint, withEvent: event)

        let view = super.hitTest(viewPoint, withEvent: event)

        return view
    }

    override public func pointInside(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        return CGRectContainsPoint(bounds, point)
    }



}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`? You can trigger this when tapping a button, in the `viewDidLoad` or in whatever other method you want it to trigger and push a new a viewController.

Firstly, set the "Storyboard ID" for the viewController in your storyboard. Like this:

[image]

Example:

Here's an example of how you can push to a new viewController when tapping a cell. As mentioned you can use this method in different functions to push to another viewController :

```
  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let yourNewView = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("yourStoryBoardID") as! ViewControllerYourePushingTo 


        self.presentViewController(yourNewView, animated: true, completion: nil)


}
```

In your case this is in the `hitTest` func.

I asked a similar question not too long ago. Here's the reference: [Swift: Triggering TableViewCell to lead to a link in a UIWebView in another ViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33201437/swift-triggering-tableviewcell-to-lead-to-a-link-in-a-uiwebview-in-another-view)

Here's the link from Apple Dev: [InstantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStoryboard_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIStoryboard/instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:)

Comment: I need to detect a tab on the bubbleView?

Comment: I didn't understand your comment. What do you mean?

Comment: Sorry i'm just not quite sure what you mean and how i can get this from hitTest?

Comment: Can you give an example of how to use it

Comment: Which method do you want to trigger a push to a new viewController?

Comment: It doesnt matter i just need some code to get going

Comment: I'll update you when I recreate it. In the mean time, have you seen this link? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28066623/customise-ios8-callout-bubble-swift

Comment: I didn't. When trying to recreate it I was slammed with bugs. This is what I would do, since I don't have your code and can't recreate it: Is your class a UITableView? If not you can add it, let me know if you need help adding it to your custom view. Once you ave this, add a didSelectCellAtIndexPath. Then add the methods I sent in the answer.

Comment: i'm using mkmapview? it is a calloutview

Comment: I'm trying to help as best I can. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14805954/mkannotationview-push-to-view-controller-when-detaildesclosure-button-is-clicked + http://nfarina.com/post/78014139253/smcalloutview-for-ios-7 do these links help? Gives me a better idea of what you're missing.

Answer (score 1):

You can add gesture on custom annotation view in didselectannotation and navigate to other view controllor from gesture action