# Swift after signup move to 2nd or any other tab of UITabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

In my App after signup/login I want to move control to specific tab of `UITabBarController` on some conditions. My login or Signup Pages are not in `UITabBarController`. 
Here is the code of my login button I have tried but it only works with identifier or `UITabBarController`. In my case I want to move to specific tab like 2nd or 3rd tab.

```
@IBAction func btn_login(sender: AnyObject) {
        activityIndicator.progressBarDisplayer("Logging In", true, uiView: self.view)
        let timezone = GLib.timezone();
        let parameters = ["email": txtemail.text!,"password": txtpassword.text!,"time_zone": timezone]
        GLib.fetch("www.abc.com/test/auth/login", parameters: parameters, localkey: "user"){
            (isResponse) -> Void in
            if(isResponse == true)
            {
                self.activityIndicator.strLabel.text = "Personalizing Data";

                let viewController:UIViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("some identifier") as UIViewController;
                self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: false, completion: nil);

              }else
              {
                self.show_alert("Attention Please!", message: self.GLib.error)
            }
}
```

I have seen many posts but found nothing similar to my mechanism.

I am new to `iOS` programming so don't know how to figure out this issue.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. When the user signs in you want to move to a specific viewController. Right?

Comment: @lukesIvi after singup  i want to move user to 2nd tab of UITabBarController

Comment: I'm assuming the 2nd viewController will always be the same VC. Your 2nd tab in the UITabBarController is a VC either way, so just give it an ID and then access it like that. I can write the answer if you need further help.

Comment: @lukeslvi can you please give me the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` is the right way to go. However, you need to add the actual identifier, and the UIViewController Custom class type needs to be the actual class.

I'm going to give you a rough example of what it looks like, but it should work. Either way you have to edit your `instantiate` method as I explain below.

**Steps:**

Firstly, set the "Storyboard ID" for the viewController in your storyboard. Like this:

[image]

Then add this code modified `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` method:

```
   @IBAction func btn_login(sender: AnyObject) {
        activityIndicator.progressBarDisplayer("Logging In", true, uiView: self.view)
        let timezone = GLib.timezone();
        let parameters = ["email": txtemail.text!,"password": txtpassword.text!,"time_zone": timezone]
        GLib.fetch("www.abc.com/test/auth/login", parameters: parameters, localkey: "user"){
            (isResponse) -> Void in
            if(isResponse == true)
            {
                self.activityIndicator.strLabel.text = "Personalizing Data";


                let yourNewViewController: ViewControllerClassName = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("yourStoryBoardID") as! ViewControllerYourePushingTo


                self.presentViewController(yourNewViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)


            }else
            {
                self.show_alert("Attention Please!", message: self.GLib.error)
            }
        }
```

As a type, you need to actually use the viewController's name.

I asked a similar question a few weeks ago: [Swift: Triggering TableViewCell to lead to a link in a UIWebView in another ViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33201437/swift-triggering-tableviewcell-to-lead-to-a-link-in-a-uiwebview-in-another-view)